# Session variable not updating after AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, pagination

I'm a tad stumped here. I have 2 php pages. One displays the template essentially,   and on click, an AJAX call calls an external page and displays all the necessary information. My problem is my session variable isn't updating. I'm using some pagination and the numbers aren't updating. Some code on my template page:

Redndering pagination

```
    session_start();
    $pagination .= $_SESSION['position'] == "" ? '' : 'Items '.$_SESSION['position'].'-'.$_SESSION['item_per_page'].' of '.$get_total_rows ;
    if($pages > 1)
        {
        $pagination .= '<ul class="paginate nav nav-pills">';
        for($i = 1; $i<=$pages; $i++)
        {
            $pagination .= '<li><a href="#" class="paginate_click" id="'.$i.'-page">'.$i.'</a></li>';
        }
        $pagination .= '</ul>';
    }
<?php echo $pagination; ?>

<div id="results">
    <!-- Results from query will go in here -->
</div>

j$(".paginate_click").click(function (e) {
    j$("#results").prepend('<div class="loading-indication"><img src="/assets/loader.gif" /></div>');
    var clicked_id = j$(this).attr("id").split("-"); //ID of clicked element, split() to get page number.
    var page_num = parseInt(clicked_id[0]); //clicked_id[0] holds the page number we need 
    j$('.paginate_click').removeClass('active'); //remove any active class
    //post page number and load returned data into result element
    //notice (page_num-1), subtract 1 to get actual starting point
    j$("#results").load("development_fetch.php", {'page': (page_num-1)}, function(){
        });
    j$(this).addClass('active'); //add active class to currently clicked element
    return false; //prevent going to herf link
});
```

in development_fetch.php:

```
session_start();
$page_number = filter_var($_POST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
$position = ($page_number * $item_per_page);
$_SESSION['position'] = $position;
$_SESSION['item_per_page'] = $item_per_page;
//Grab code to display inside template blah.
```

If you click on page 1 in the pagination, it should result in:

> Items 0 - 100 of 1000

If I click page 2, it should be:

> Items 100 - 200 of 1000

but instead it just stays at:

> Items 0 - 100 of 1000

0 is the `$_SESSION['position']`
100 is the `$_SESSION['item_per_page']`

I don't understand why it isn't updating. Please help stackers!

Comment: `session_start();` on **every** page please.

Comment: Forgot yo mention, session_start() is on every page

Comment: can you return a `print_r($_POST);` from ajax to see what actually goes to ajax?

Comment: In the development_fetch.php is where I placed the code. I got this result Array ( [page] => 0 )

Comment: wherever pagination you click the result `Array ( [page] ` is 0 ?

Comment: the `id="'.$i.'-page"` of your `paginate_click`'s should not start with a number. its not valid it should start with a letter `AZaz` so i dont know if jquery manages eventually to grab that value to `var page_num`

Comment: @Sharky the print_r was pasted towards the top on the development_fetch.php if I click on page 2, the result is 1, if I click page 3, the result is 2 and so on.

Answer (score 2):

i already solved mine. the issue i'm having is that, when i'm doing the ajax, the session variable is not updating in realtime. what i did, is that, i just turned the ajax asynchronous to false, since when you are doing the asynchronous, the value being cache is not the updated value since it is in asynchronous mode. if you are using jquery, just do this:

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'url',
  data: 'the datas',
  success: function() {},
  async: false
});

Answer (score 1):

Put `session_start();` at the begining of the page loaded with AJAX.

Comment: It's already been added into both pages, forgot to add it here in my snippets, sorry!

Comment: $item_per_page is unassigned in ajax page. Pass that value too just like you passed the page number or assign it with the value you prefer, if you want it to be unchanged.

Comment: Sory for late reply. $item_per_page is a global variable which is located in an include file :)

Comment: did you include that file (that contains $item_per_page global variable) on AJAX page?

Comment: Yes I did! I'm still stumped over it!

Answer (score 0):

i think i found it, in your `development_fetch.php`

```
$position = ($page_number * $item_per_page);
```

okay, `$page_number` has a value, but what about `$item_per_page` ? i guess its zero, and the result of multiplication of course is zero. Then you set those zeroes on the `$_SESSION`

solution:

set your `$item_per_page`

```
session_start();
$item_per_page = 20;
// ...rest of code
```

Comment: Hey mate, I have added $item_per_page as part of an include file and i'm still having the same issue!

Comment: @AkiraDawson if you set it in `development_fetch.php` does it works?

Comment: The development_fetch.php has the same include file which includes the $item_per_page variable

Comment: @AkiraDawson please answer on my previous comment :)

Answer (score 0):

i also got this issue, but mine was acting weird. it seems that the session was not fast enough to catch with the ajax.. is this problem already resolved?

Comment: It is not resolved unfortunately. I rewrote my code to get mine working :( I had to do naughty naughty. I do have plans to come back to it and make it better